# How to make input fields not falling into new line for inline form of bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have an inline form that its input fields are more longer width than screen therefore some fields fall into new line.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Inline form</h1>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="flex-wrap: nowrap; overflow-x: scroll;">
      <form>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-2">
            <label for="">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <label for="">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <label for="">Gender</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Gender">
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <label for="">Age</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Age">
          </div>

          <div class="col-2">
            <label for="">Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address">
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <label for="">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number">
          </div>

          <div class="col-2">
            <label for="">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <label for="">Website</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Website">
          </div>

        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

  <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Understanding the bootstrap column should not exceed 12 columns width per row, but since I have many fields I want those those fields go into one single row with scroll bar.

How can I do that? Even thought, I set style `flex-wrap: nowrap; overflow-x: scroll;` to class `.row` already, it is still not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you achive this using adding `flex-nowrap` class in `.form-row` div

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Inline form</h1>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="flex-wrap: nowrap; overflow-x: scroll;">
      <form>
        <div class="form-row flex-nowrap">
          <div class="col-2">
            <label for="">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <label for="">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <label for="">Gender</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Gender">
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <label for="">Age</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Age">
          </div>

          <div class="col-2">
            <label for="">Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address">
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <label for="">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number">
          </div>

          <div class="col-2">
            <label for="">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <label for="">Website</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Website">
          </div>

        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

  <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `col-2` class to just `col` and everything lays out on one line.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Inline form</h1>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="flex-wrap: nowrap; overflow-x: scroll;">
      <form>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col">
            <label for="">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <label for="">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <label for="">Gender</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Gender">
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <label for="">Age</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Age">
          </div>

          <div class="col">
            <label for="">Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address">
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <label for="">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number">
          </div>

          <div class="col">
            <label for="">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <label for="">Website</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Website">
          </div>

        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

  <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```